# Strange error without message when saving an object in Parse.com

Tags: jquery, parse-platform, save, runtime-error

I have been using Parse for the last weeks now that I have been creating an App that save some "products". It has been working fine by now, but I found a strange bug that I cannot debug or find a reason why it is failing.

Simplifying, I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+
| Name | Type | Price | Stock |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| Foo  | Bar  | 1.00  | true  |
```

The code for saving is, in general, the same as de documentation:

'saveProducts': function() {

```
// get products

// validate products

// save products
product.save(null, {
  success: function(product) {
      console.log("Saved");
      console.log(product);
  },
  error: function(product, error) {
      console.log("Error");
      console.log(product);
      console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Until now, this have been working fine because all objects were like this:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+
| Name | Type | Price | Stock |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| Foo  | Bar  | 1.00  | true  |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| Baz  | Coo  | 2.00  | true  |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| Sun  | Low  | 3.00  | true  |
```

Getting in the console:

```
f {_serverData: Object, _opSetQueue: Array[1], attributes: Object, _hashedJSON: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object…}
  _allPreviousSaves: b.Promise 
  _changing: false
  _escapedAttributes: Object
  _existed: true
  _hasData: true
  _hashedJSON: Object
  _opSetQueue: Array[1]
  _pending: Object
  _previousAttributes: Object
  _saving: 0
  _serverData: Object
  _silent: Object
  attributes: Object
  changed: Object
  cid: "c133"
  createdAt: Thu May 14 2015 15:31:25 GMT+0200 (CEST)
  id: "XBMruz5vZb"
  updatedAt: Thu May 14 2015 15:31:26 GMT+0200 (CEST)
  __proto__: f
```

As you can see, there is an `id` and a `createdAt` fields.

But when I tried saving a file with `Stock` set to `false` I get:

```
f {_serverData: Object, _opSetQueue: Array[1], attributes: Object, _hashedJSON: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object…}
  _escapedAttributes: Object
  _hasData: true
  _hashedJSON: Object
  _opSetQueue: Array[1]
  _pending: Object
  _previousAttributes: Object
  _serverData: Object
  _silent: Object
  attributes: Object
  changed: Object
  cid: "c135"
  __proto__: f
```

No `id`, no `createdAt`. And the error I get is this:

```
[false]
```

Full stop. And if I create the same object with `Stock` set to `true` instead, it saves it just fine.

Any ideas why is this happening?

#### EDIT

This is an extended version of my method:

```
'saveProduct': function() {

  // Gets data
  var data = this.getDataFromForm();

  if(this.validateData(data)) {

    var name  = data[0],
    type      = data[1],
    price     = data[3],
    stock     = data[4];

    var productData = {'name'  : name,
                       'type'  : type,
                       'price' : Number(price),
                       'stock' : stock
                      };

    var product = new window.app.Product();
    // window.app.Product is defined as a Model:
    // window.app.Product = Parse.Object.extend("Product", { ... });

    // And here comes the Parse save function
    product.save(productData, {
    ...
    });
  }
}
```

#### UPDATE 2

This is what I get when I print `stock`:

```
false
```

It is a boolean, not a String.

This is what I get when a print `productData`:

```
Object {name: "Foo", type: "Bar "…}
  name: "Foo"
  price: 1
  type: "Bar"
  stock: false
  __proto__: Object
```

Comment: How are you setting it to `true` or `false`? Are you sure that the code is actually setting it to `false` correctly?

Comment: I will update the question with that information!

Comment: I don't see you using `Parse.Object` anywhere. Take a look at the [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects)

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with a few more information. I am using Parse.Objects, I was not showing it.

Comment: This goes back to my previous point. Are you sure `data[4]` contains a proper `boolean` when you think it is `false`?

Comment: Do you have any beforeSave functions in Cloud Code that might reject a `false` value for that field?

Comment: @Jack I even tried hardcoding it, I updated the question with what I get from  `console.log(stock)` and `console.log(productData)`

Comment: @BjörnKaiser I don't have any Cloud Code. At least not that I have done by myself.